# php eval() error after updating

Tags: php, eval

I cant seem to find the error in here, this code used to work then I updated PHP and now I get :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '10' (T_LNUMBER) in C:\wamp\www\a\1.php(15) : eval()'d code on line 1

```
$operande1 = 5;
$operande2 = 10;
$operation = "*";
calcul($operande1,$operande2,$operation);
function calcul($operande1, $operande2, $operation) {
                echo $operande1;
                echo $operande2;
                echo $operation;
                eval('$result=('.$operande1.")".$operation."(".$operande2.");");
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Code looks OK, but you should not use eval() with user provided data, because it may cause severe security issues.

Comment: PHP updating has nothing to do with it.  All PHP versions on 3v4l.org show the same output (which is `"510*"`). See http://3v4l.org/smfWE#v430

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're concatenating a string with a number in the eval. Wrapping the `$operande1` inside `strval($operande1)` should solve this. I don't recommend using eval at all but, it would look like this, another option is to simply have the numbers as strings, by initializing them inside quotation marks ie `$operande1 = "10";`

```
eval('$result=('.strval($operande1).")".$operation."(".strval($operande2).");");
```

**Note** that the `eval` is just setting the value to the variable `$result`, and you'll to do `echo $result;` to print its value.

Comment: What's wrong with concatenating strings with numbers? PHP automatically converts the string to a number, there's no need to call a function for it.

Comment: Sheer curiosity here, but why eval would not be able to deal with int ?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to reproduce the error that you posted

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '10' (T_LNUMBER)

was to leave out the `=` sign.

```
$operande1  10;
```

which gave me

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '10' (T_LNUMBER)

---

http://3v4l.org/o1vDg

> Output for 5.4.0 - 5.6.2, php7@20140507 - 20141001
>       Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '10' (T_LNUMBER) in /in/o1vDg on line 3